# How can I test if an element is of type Any

Tags: go, types, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, protobuf-go

How can I test if an element of a structure is of type Any (protobuf):  *any.Any, in Go?
I want to go through each element of a structure, and do a switch case depending on the type of the element.
Here is the field descriptor of the message:

```
FieldDescriptor{Syntax: proto3, FullName:, Number: 3, Cardinality: optional, Kind: message, HasJSONName: true, JSONName:, HasPresence: true, Oneof:, Message: google.protobuf.Any}
```

Here is my code:

```
func doSomething(src protoreflect.Message) {
    src.Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {
            switch {
            case fd.IsList():
                // do something
            case fd.IsMap():
                // do something
            case fd.Message() != nil:
                // do something
            case fd.Kind() == protoreflect.BytesKind:
                // do something
            case *test if message is Any* :
                // do something
            default:
                // do something
            }
        return true
        })
}
```

I would like a more correct way than for ex:

```
if fd.Message() != nil{
     fd.Message().FullName() == "google.protobuf.Any"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a switch case to type check.

```golang
 switch v := fd.(type) { 
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T", v)
    case string:
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: It won't work since fd.(type) is *filedesc.Field